# How bad is it if I use inable rather than unable?

Tags: word-choice, archaicisms

Reading on wikitionary as well as many other dictionary sites, the word inable is "obselete" or "rare". However, just in my internal monologue I use that word all the time, and to me it sounds better in certain contexts. Would it be frowned upon if I were to use inable rather than unable in an essay, or is it ok to do so?

Comment: What dictionaries other than Wiktionary (and sites that copy Wiktionary) have this word? I checked the OED and didn't find it, although it does list "inhabile" as an obsolete word meaning "unable".

Comment: Whether it would be frowned upon depends on your potential frowner. Some teachers might welcome archaic spellings (especially if you did this intentionally in a literary context), whereas others might simply run the spell checker and mark you down. Yet others might think you’re imitating ‘preschooler spelling’. We not in a good position to answer that question, unfortunately.

Comment: If you used it in conversation, I would think you had said "enable", which would probably leave me "inable" to comprehend your meaning.  :-) In text, I would probably assume you were either (a) a poor speller or (b) a poor proofreader, but either way it would reflect badly on your essay.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inable#:~:text=inable%20(not%20comparable),nonstandard)%20Unable%2C%20not%20able.)  flags 'inable' as 'obsolete, now nonstandard'. Which is 'worse' than it regards 'thou'. Isn't this totally clear?

Comment: Do we have to entertain questions of this kind?

Comment: What happened 3 hours ago to warrant this level of necroposting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The new usage is to use "un" instead of "in". But it's not that simple.

Affixes.org explains:

- **[in](http://www.affixes.org/i/in-1.html)** - Not; without.

> [Latin in-.]
>
> This prefix is added to adjectives to give a negative sense (infertile, inarticulate, inexpensive, invariable) and to nouns to indicate a lack of something (inattention, incapacity, insensitivity). Many examples exist, but in- is not a living form, new words instead being created using un-, to which it is closely related in sense. There is no clear rule deciding which should be used: see un- for more information. See also the next entry.
>
> The prefix is spelled il- before stems beginning in l (illegitimate, illiberal), im- before b, m, and p (imbalance, immoral, impossible), and ir- before r (irrational, irregular).

- **[un](http://www.affixes.org/u/un-.html)** - Negation; reversal of a state.

> [Old English prefixes un- and on-, of Germanic origin.]
>
> This prefix occurs extremely widely; the majority of adjectives, adverbs, and verbs (and many nouns) can in principle be given it to create a new word indicating an opposite or a reversal.
>
> A very few of the many examples in the sense of ‘not’ are unconnected, unenclosed, unfashionable, unhappy, unloved, unmade, unsuitable, and unwilling. In this sense, un- often has a stronger and less neutral force than just negation (so it is not equivalent to non-): unkind can mean active cruelty rather than a simple lack of kindness; to say someone is un-American can imply an active antagonism to American ways.
>
> With verbs, it usually has the sense of reversing some state: unblock, unburden, unhook, unlace, unsettle, unstick, untie, unwind, unzip.
>
> Un- is closely related in sense to in-, but **although the latter prefix is common it is no longer active**. There is no good rule to decide which is the right form in any given situation and terms have to be learnt. **To confuse matters somewhat, some noun-adjective pairs use different prefixes: instability corresponds to unstable; inequality to unequal; injustice to unjust. In a few cases, pairs of adjectives exist in both prefixes with similar senses: inadvisable and unadvisable; incommunicative and uncommunicative. In a few other pairs, members have significantly different senses, as with unhuman, not resembling or having the qualities of a human being, versus inhuman, lacking human qualities of compassion and mercy**.

Comment: So? Eh, Rob? (Even the name is too short to fill in for minimum characters.)

Comment: [@Kris](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback), so!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use it as it's not used at all. Check lengusa, literally zero results :

[lengusa | inable](https://lengusa.com/search/inable)

What I can suggest you is spending some time and effort to replace it even in your internal monologue. I am not a native speaker too and that's what I do.

Comment: The poster should have done (and included) basic research; the question should be closed. Answering merely encourages other such questions, damaging the site's credibility.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I thought maybe I can help some fellow non-native speaker person but it is super lazy to ask it like that.

Comment: Does this work? https://ludwig.guru/s/inable
They are similar websites. They just show lots of examples from reliable contexts. I like this format. Is it wrong?

Answer (score -2):

This is probably not much help, but here it is anyway:

Personally, I have nothing against either word and use whichever sounds better in the situation I need it for, but that's *just my opinion.*

I also have this *headcanon* that *unable* is more to do with the situation (Ex.: [someone] is *unable* to drive [somewhere] because a tree fell over and blocked the road), whilst *inable* is more to do with the subject (Ex.: [someone] is *inable* to drive [somewhere] because they're too sleep-deprived to drive), this is also *just subjective and not to be taken as fact.*